# How can I run a simple for loop instead of recurring if-statements?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I'm am trying to write a piece of code that reads 5 inputs and then works out the lowest input given through a for-loop. Currently I have written 4 if-statements to make this happen, however I'm wondering if I can write a simple for-loop for this. The point is not to use an array to save the input. This is my code:

```
int smallestNumb = 0;
int largestNumb = 0;

Scanner numbIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");
int number1 = numbIn.nextInt();
int number2 = numbIn.nextInt();
int number3 = numbIn.nextInt();
int number4 = numbIn.nextInt();
int number5 = numbIn.nextInt();

smallestNumb = number1;

if(smallestNumb > number2) {
    smallestNumb = number2;
}

if(smallestNumb >  number3) {
    smallestNumb = number3;
}

if(smallestNumb > number4) {
    smallestNumb = number4;
}

if(smallestNumb > number5){
    smallestNumb = number5;
}
```

Comment: So I have to use an array to do this with a for loop?

Comment: Maybe define something as a scanner termination condition and read the scanner in a while loop and keep track of the smallest and largest value encountered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop to ask 5 times the question, and for each check if the new one is smaller

```
int smallestNumb = Integer.MAX_VALUE, choice;
Scanner numbIn = new Scanner(System.in);

for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    choice = numbIn.nextInt();
    if(smallestNumb > choice) {
        smallestNumb = choice;
    }
}

System.out.println(smallestNumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int smallestNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Scanner numIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");

    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        num = numIn.nextInt();
        if(num < smallestNum)
            smallestNum = num;
    }

    System.out.println(smallestNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method with a var args (I don't handle the empty case) :

```
public int getSmallest(int... numbers){
  int smallestNumb = numbers[0];
  if (numbers.length==1) 
    return smallestNumb;

  for (int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++){
    smallestNumb = Math.min(smallestNumb, numbers[i]);
  }
  return smallestNumb;
}
```

and use it :

```
int smallest = getSmallest(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)
```

Or chain `Math.min()` such as :

```
smallestNumb = number1;
smallestNumb = Math.min(smallestNumb, number2);
smallestNumb = Math.min(smallestNumb, number3);
smallestNumb = Math.min(smallestNumb, number4);
smallestNumb = Math.min(smallestNumb, number5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the smallest number on the fly:

```
Scanner numbIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");

int smallestNumb = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int num = numbIn.nextInt();
    smallestNumb = num < smallestNumb ? num : smallestNumb;
}
```